# MySQL (MariaDB) while loop

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, lamp

Hey there,

I'm trying to update a table with rack and shelf locations in our storage 
room. there are 15 racks and each rack has 5 shelves. I'm running the loop to 20 to add some extra locations for when we get more shelves. So far this is the procedure I've been trying torun, but; I am getting a syntax error near my first END IF;

Here is my statement:

```
    drop PROCEDURE if exists updateLocations;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE updateLocations()
    begin
    DECLARE rack INT default 1;
    DECLARE shelf INT default 1;
    WHILE rack<21 DO
        insert into tblStorageLocations values ("", rack, shelf);
            IF (shelf=5, SET rack=rack+1, set rack=rack);
            END IF;
            IF (shelf<5, SET shelf=shelf+1, set shelf=1);
            END IF;
            END WHILE;
END;
    //
    DELIMITER ;


    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF;

    IF (shelf<5, SET shelf=shelf+1, set shelf=1);
    END IF;
    END WHILE' at line 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are processing `if` as a function, rather than as a statement.

```
drop PROCEDURE if exists updateLocations;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE updateLocations()
BEGIN
    DECLARE rack INT default 1;
    DECLARE shelf INT default 1;
    WHILE rack < 21 DO
        INSERT INTO tblStorageLocations 
            VALUES ('', rack, shelf);
        IF shelf = 5 THEN
            SET rack = rack + 1;
        END IF;
        IF shelf < 5 THEN
            SET shelf = shelf + 1;
        ELSE 
            SET shelf = 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was misunderstanding!